# Dynamic Sql Error , Invalid syntax near '>'

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have the below dynamic sql statement and I'm getting the "Incorrect syntax near '>'. error message. I can not figure out what the problem is, not sure if I'm missing a tick mark or not. I've tried to add extra tick marks and nothing seems to work.

```
Declare @filters varchar(max)
SET @filters = 'Where PaymentAmount > 0'
BEGIN 
SET @filters = @filters + ' AND CONVERT(DATE, AccountingDate) >= '''+ cast @BeginDate as nvarchar) + ''''
SET @filters = @filters + ' AND CONVERT(DATE, AccountingDate) <= '''+ cast(@EndDate as nvarchar) + ''''
END

SET @SQLString = 'Select 
  ,[ReturnDate]
  ,[PolicyNumber]
From dbo.Bil_ReturnsRepository' + @filters

EXEC(@SQLString)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need another space before you concat @filters to @SQLString.

```
SET @SQLString = 'Select 
  ,[ReturnDate]
  ,[PolicyNumber]
From dbo.Bil_ReturnsRepository ' + @filters
```

Otherwise the generated sql would be

```
...
From dbo.Bil_ReturnsRepositoryWhere PaymentAmount > 0
...
```

Comment: wow. thank you very much. my eyes are hurting from starting at this for hours now. lol. sometimes it takes a fresh set of eyes. thanks again!

Comment: @Jason heh, I know your pain :)